# Try to reach docker container from python script (Interactive brokers)

Tags: python, docker, synology, interactive-brokers

On my synology I have this docker container running: https://registry.hub.docker.com/r/mgvazquez/ibgateway/

In the "manual" is says: "In this example you will launch the Interactive Brokers Gateway in paper mode listening on port 4001, and the VNC Server listening on port 5900"

So in the docker container I did the following port mapping:

Local port 32778 to container 5900 and local port 32776 to container 4001. My Synology Nas is 192.168.2.6.

When I connect from my local pc using vnc to 192.168.2.6:32778 it works perfectly.

Now, In my Python script I do:

```
from ib_insync import *
ib = IB()

# use this instead for IB Gateway
ib.connect('192.168.2.6:32776', 4002, clientId=1)
```

The 4002 is a socket port setting inside the gateway.

When I run the script I get "Getaddrinfo failed". Does not make sense to me.

What can be the issue here?

Comment: Where do you run the code? What error do you get exactly, including the traceback?

Comment: I run the code in Visual studio code on my workstation.
When I debug I get this message:
"Exception has occurred: gaierror
[Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
  File "Y:\broker\demo.py", line 6, in <module>
    ib.connect('192.168.2.6:32776', 4002, clientId=1)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to API document at https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-ib_insync.ib

connect use following syntax:

```
connect(host='127.0.0.1', port=7497, clientId=1, timeout=4, readonly=False, account='')
```

host (str) – Host name or IP address.

port (int) – Port number.

clientId (int) – ID number to use for this client; must be unique per connection. Setting clientId=0 will automatically merge manual TWS trading with this client.

timeout (float) – If establishing the connection takes longer than timeout seconds then the asyncio.TimeoutError exception is raised. Set to 0 to disable timeout.

readonly (bool) – Set to True when API is in read-only mode.

account (str) – Main account to receive updates for.

so your code:

```
# use this instead for IB Gateway
ib.connect('192.168.2.6:32776', 4002, clientId=1)
```

should be changed to:

```
# use this instead for IB Gateway
ib.connect('192.168.2.6', 32776, clientId=1)
```

Comment: YES, thanks. I got my code from a tutorial (without Docker). Obviously wrong implementation from me. Great!

Answer (score 0):

First, just for testing, try and use port 4001 directly:

```
ib.connect('192.168.2.6:32776', 4002, clientId=1)
```

Second, check your [IB `socat` service is running](https://github.com/mgvazquez/ibgateway/blob/475223cb13ce14cf21224c59117105e226fbdb36/components/services/socat/run), since it is that service which  establishes two bidirectional byte streams and transfers data between 4001 and 4002:

```
echo "Starting Interactive Brokers Controller" | info
exec socat TCP-LISTEN:4001,fork TCP:127.0.0.1:4002 2>&1 | info
```

The Dockerfile [registers it](https://github.com/mgvazquez/ibgateway/blob/9f7eaa0b8f3ba4fea3a3bf947798ecdf8511c713/Dockerfile#L34).
Try and add a mapping for port 4002.

Comment: Thanks, I tried:
ib.connect('192.168.2.6:32776', 4001, clientId=1) in all kind of ways
Added a mapping for port 4002, no luck either.
How can I check if IB socat service is running?

Comment: @hacking_mike Like any service, `service socat status` (as `root`)

Comment: When I check it in processes of the container it is executed without error.

Comment: Mapping to 4002 also did not work.

Comment: @hacking_mike You can execute commands with a `docker exec -it <yourContainer> bash`